# Generate random number that follows a probability distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a probability distribution described from a function, let's say a gaussian distribution (with coefficient `1/sqrt(pi)`, that makes the following area `1`):

```
import math
D = lambda x: pow(math.e, -pow(x,2)) / math.sqrt(math.pi)
```

The previous function would plot the following graph
[image]

If I used that gaussian function as a probability distribution I would have more probability to receive a `0` back than any other number.

Is there a way to generate a random number that follows that distribution?

Comment: There is literally an entire [book](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html) dedicated to this topic, so I'd say that your question is far too broad.  Even your "let's say..." example of the Gaussian has multiple ways to generate - Box-Muller, polar method, ziggurat method, acceptance/rejection, to name a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use scipy.stats.

We inherit from rv_continuous and specify the probability density function `_pdf`. Next, we use the inherited method `rvs()` to draw a random sample.

```
import math
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous


class MyRandomVariable(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return pow(math.e, -pow(x,2)) / math.sqrt(math.pi)
    
    
my_random_variable = MyRandomVariable()

samples = [my_random_variable.rvs() for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some common random distributions in the built in [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) library.

below I've generated 1k random numbers following the gauss and log normal

```py
import random

x = [random.gauss(10, 2) for r in range(1000)]

y = [random.lognormvariate(10, 2) for x in range(1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `scipy.stats` library.  From the documentation page for the normal distribution https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html:

```
from scipy.stats import norm # Import library
r = norm.rvs(size=1000) # Draw 1000 random variates
```

Also note that it is a probability density, so the probability of drawing any particular number (including 0) is in fact 0.